# terminating app with signal 6 in xcode

Tags: ios6

my project is working fine when i not upgrade xcode to ios 6..
but after upgrading i ve this error...

collect2: ld terminated with signal 6 [Abort trap: 6]
ld(22918,0x7fff72e6f960) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe300c4d130: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

i tried much to find this on net but dont find any similer problem or any solution..
please need help soon....

Comment: Did you try as the message suggests to "set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug"?  Here are search results on SO for that message: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22set+a+breakpoint+in+malloc_error_break+to+debug%22

Answer (score 8):

All of a sudden this happens to me as well, clear and build solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also got a problem with exit code signal 6. In my case, the problem was, I defined the `UIStoryboard` at `Build as:` with a `iOS` version higher than the `UIDevice` I was installing the app.

Maybe you are going to check this, didn't have this problem before, so might be possible it solves yours too.

Here a screenshot where to go inside the `File Inspectore`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the error.  And it was caused by the wrong usage of `UserDefault` class.  As you know, the `UserDefault` methods should be executed in the UI thread(main thread) and you are restricted to types to be saved. I called the `UserDefault` methods in not main thread and I also tried to save `struct`. And then I got **message from debugger: terminated due to signal 6**.  Finally, I made the execution thread the main thread and the type `dictionary`. And I overcame this error.

Comment: For me, it was also related to threading. When I wrapped the erroring code into a dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue) it is solved.

Answer (score 1):

This is related to updating the UI in a background thread. 
You should change the UI in the main thread.

Comment: My flutter App is crash with the same reason after iOS 13 update. It was working without issue on emulator and iOS 12

Answer (score 1):

Disable thread sanitizer from 
Edit Scheme -> Run -> Uncheck Thread Sanitizer.

Comment: **this!** why, I don't know but **this!**